# Is there an API for Post Inspector, allowing for example Pabbly och Zapier to trigger it automatically?

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there an API for Post Inspector, allowing for example Pabbly och Zapier to trigger it automatically?

The use case is I have websites were pages are often updated and recurringly shared on LinkedIn. Since the caching on LinkedIn doesn't seem to refresh very often, I need ot do this via Post Inspector before re-sharing the page.